# Spivak: if $y''+y=0$, $y$ is not the $0$ function, $s=ay+by'$ then $s''+s=0$. Can we conclude $y$ and $s$ are infinitely many times differentiable?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

I think perhaps the simplest form of this question is: if $y''+y=0$ and $y$ isn't the $0$ function, then can we conclude that $y$ is infinitely many times differentiable?

This question came about when proving part $(c)$ of a problem from Chapter 15 of Spivak's *Calculus*, which I show further below.

In that problem, we eventually have

$$s=ay+by'$$
$$\implies s''+s=0$$

and we assume

$$s(0)=0$$
$$s'(0)=1$$

Can we conclude that $s$ is infinitely times differentiable?

That is, since $s=-s''$ then $s$ is twice differentiable. But then $s'=-s'''$, so $s$ must be three times differentiable. But then $s''=s^{(4)}$ so $s$ is four times differentiable.

Is this reasoning correct?

**Here is the problem from Spivak's *Calculus***

> *30. If we are willing to assume that certain differential equations have solutions, another approach to the trigonometric functions is
> possible. Suppose, in particular, that there is some function $y_0$
> which is not always $0$ and which satisfies $y_0''+y_0=0$.
>
> (a) Prove that $y_0^2+(y_0')^2$ is constant, and conclude that either
> $y_0(0)\neq 0$ or $y_0'(0)\neq 0$.
>
> (b) Prove that there is a function $s$ satisfying $s''+s=0$ and
> $s(0)=0$ and $s'(0)=1$ Hint: try $s$ of the form $ay_0+by_0'$.
>
> If we define $\sin=s$ and $\cos=s'$, then almost all facts about
> trigonometric functions become trivial. There is one point which
> requires work, however - producing the number $\pi$. This is most
> easily done using an exercise from Appendix to Chapter 11:
>
> (c) Use Problem 6 of the Appendix to Chapter 11 to prove that
> $\cos{x}$ cannot be positive for all $x>0$. It follows that there is a
> smallest $x_0>0$ with $\cos{x_0}=$, and we can define $\pi=2x_0$.

**Let me try to understand what is being done here.**

We assume the differential equation $$f'+f=0\tag{1}$$ has a solution other than the function $0$. We name this assumed-to-exist function $y_0$. Then, $(a)$ shows that this function satisfies another differential equation
$$y_0^2+(y_0')^2=\text{constant}\tag{2}$$

and at $0$, $y_0$ and $y_0'$ cannot both be $0$ simultaneously.

These are simply consequences of a function existing that satisfies $(1)$.

Now we define another function

$$s=ay_0+by_0'$$

Turns out this function has the same property as $y_0$: it satisfies the differential equation $(1)$, ie

$$s''+s=0$$

If we make further assumptions, that $s(0)=0$ and $s'(0)=1$, then we obtain two linear equations in $a$ and $b$, and we can show that a solution always exists (the determinant of the system of equations is $$-[(y_0(0))^2+(y_0'(0))^2]\neq 0$$

which is probably why we proved what we did in $(a)$ (when we proved $(a)$ we also showed that the constant is different from $0$).

At this point we've constructed a function $s$ such that

$$s''+s=0$$
$$s(0)=0$$
$$s'(0)=1$$

**In the proof of part $(c)$ we will eventually need $s'$ to be twice differentiable. Can we conclude that $s$ is infinitely many times differentiable just from the three equations above?**

Just to conclude the attempt at understanding the problem, we know that $s'$ is continuous, $s'(0)=1$ and that there is an $x>0$ such that $s'(x)\leq 0$ (we know this after proving part $(c)$). Thus the set

$$\{x:x>0\land s'(x)\leq 0\}$$

has an infimum. Let's call this infimum $x_0$. Then, Spivak defines $\pi$ as $2x_0$.

Comment: $s''=-s$, a twice differentiable function, so $s$ is four-times differentiable. But then $s''$ equals a four-times differentiable function, so $s$ is siz-times differentiable, and so on.

Comment: $y''+y=0$, then $y$ is twice differentiable, then $y''=-y$ is also twice differentiable, then $y''''=-(y'')=y$ is also twice differentiable and so on.

Comment: If a function is twice differentiable, doesn't this imply that it is differentiable? If so then doesn't this mean that $y''$ is also differentiable? Ie, can't we avoid the thing where you consider  only $y''$, $y^{(4)}$, $y^{(6)}$, etc?

Comment: In the general existence proof you transform a differential equation into an integral equation, $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(0)=y_0$ to $y(x)=y_0+\int_0^x f(t,y(t))\,dt$. In the fixed-point argument, this maps continuous functions to continuous functions. In the conclusion, this also proves that $y\in C^1$. In an extended conclusion, if $y\in C^k$ and as long as $f\in C^k$, then also $y\in C^{k+1}$. So if $f\in C^\infty$, then in the end also $y\in C^\infty$. ((The step from $f\in C^\omega$ to $y\in C^\omega$ is an almost completely separate argument.))

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is somewhat correct but not satisfactory, as it looks like it is circular. In establishing your reason that $s'''$ exists you are already using the existence of $s'''$ in writing down the differentiated equation.

It is better to go the other way, using integration. Use Taylor expansion with remainder term (partial integration, mean value theorems) to establish
$$
s(t)=s(0)+s'(0)t+\int_0^t(t-u)s''(u)\,du=s(0)+s'(0)t-\int_0^t(t-u)s(u)\,du.
$$
As integration increases the smoothness class, you can now conclude that if $s\in C^2$, then already $s\in C^3$, which implies $s\in C^4$ etc.

Comment: You say the reasoning looks circular. But is it actually circular? When we write $s=-s''$ we are saying that the second derivative is the negative of the original function. But the original function is differentiable, so the second derivative, being the same exact function but negative, is also differentiable. Is this circular? I have not reached the chapter on Taylor expansion yet so that is not available to me yet.

Comment: @evianpring : Yes, in this form or like in the first comment under the question it is not circular. In this argument the integration is implicit, I just made an explicit version of it.